# ¿Por qué soy redireccionado al método index cuando hago una petición post desde el Postman?

Tags: php, laravel, api, post, postman

He estado realizando un api de ejemplo con Laravel 7 desde donde gestiono empleados. Con este objetivo, declaré las rutas de acceso a los métodos de **EmpleadoController** en el fichero **api.php**. Cuando consumo desde el **Postman** los métodos que van por GET, todo funcionan bien, pero cuando consumo el método **store** (POST) me redirecciona al método **index** y no se por qué. He puesto en el Postman los datos del empleado en el **Body** en la seccion **from-data** y también probé ponerlos en **x-www-from-urlencoded** pero siempre soy redireccionado al **index**, (algo que he notado es que cuando los datos los mando por POST me llega un arreglo vacio al método store del controller). He buscado pero hasta ahora no he encontrado la solución al problema. Desde ya les agradesco por su tiempo y colaboración

A continuación muestro las rutas tal y como las tengo en el **api.php**

**Route::resources(['empleados' => 'EmpleadoController']);**

Esta es la salida que recibo al ejecutar **php artisan route:list**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la vista del Postman (al enviar la petición me redireccionó al metodo index)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask]. Por otro lado, evita subir imagenes, es mejor que *copies y pegues* el código de lo que estás haciendo. Saludos

Comment: Eso suena a que la configuración del servidor es la que hace la redirección y la URL que intentas consumir sólo recibe GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, probé poner las rutas por separado en lugar de declararlas resource tal y como muestro a continuación:

**Route::get('listar_empleados','EmpleadoController@index')->name('empleados.index');
Route::get('muestra_empleado/{id}','EmpleadoController@show')->name('empleados.show');
Route::post('inserta_empleado','EmpleadoController@store')->name('empleados.store');**

De esta forma pude realizar la petición satisfactoriamente, luego por curiosidad volví a poner la ruta que tenía al inicio en lugar de las otras:

**Route::resources(['empleados' => 'EmpleadoController']);**

esta vez funcionó como debería, realmente no tengo idea que pudo ser porque fuera de esto no hice nada más, pero después de hecho los pasos que comenté, problema resuelto . Gracias por su tiempo.